# what's meaning of "expressly found that"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> The judge **expressly** **found that** the material risks (sovereign default,
>   currency default and counterparty default), were all disclosed and
>   known to AP.

Could you kindly explain what "expressly found that" means in the sentence as above?

I know what both "expressly" and "found that" mean, but I'm not sure what "expressly found that" means.

Answer (score 1):

These is a legal expression, and you will not find it outside that context.

It is saying that the judge said specifically (rather than referring to it, or implying it by choice of words) that the risks were disclosed etc

Comment: You definitely find *expressly* outside of legal contexts, at least in the U.S. [See Merriam-Webster's quotes](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expressly).

Comment: I was thinking of the collocation, @PeterShor. _Found that_ normally refer to somebody discovering something, not somebody expressing something, and so _expressly found that_ is incoherent in most ordinary contexts .

Comment: @ColinFine I don't tend to agree. Anyone who is outputting conclusions could expressly find something -- a committee, for instance.

Comment: @MikeGraham: OK. There are 31 instances of _expressly found that_ in the iWeb corpus. One of them is referring to a research paper, so yes, it can occur outside legal contexts. The other 30 all have a court, judge, jury, or magistrate as the subject.

Comment: *Expressly* in the legal context typically means “written” or “expressed” in some permanent medium, as opposed to a verbal statement, implication etc. With nothing else to go by here, I would interpret *expressly found* as something the judge wrote in a legal document, as opposed to a verbal statement made in the courtroom.

Comment: When judges "find for party A", they are judging and deciding. This use of found is not _found a taxi_, but concluded some decision and stated explicitly the reasoning that led to that conclusion.

Comment: @GlobalCharm: I strongly dispute that interpretation. I don't recognise _expressly_ as meaning "written as opposed to verbal", and I have looked in several dictionaries, including the OED, and not found that meaning.

Answer (score 0):

the term find is the verb for the noun finding

It means:

**Finding**
The result of the deliberations of a jury or a court. A decision upon a Question of Fact reached as the result of a judicial examination or investigation by a court, jury, referee, Coroner, etc. A recital of the facts as found. **The word commonly applies to the result reached by a judge or jury**. [bolding mine]

*West's Encyclopedia of American Law, edition 2. Copyright 2008 The Gale Group, Inc. All rights reserved*.

If a judge expressly finds [something] he or she is explicitly or clearly stating something.

Sometimes, in legal language, one can infer a judge meant this or that even if he or she did not expressly (clearly) state the thing.

The past tense is found.

You will often see in newspaper articles, expressions like: "The jury found for the plaintiff" (in AmE) and that means that claims made or brought by a plaintiff or respondent have been agreed to by the jury.